# Curly braces inside bash function

Tags: bash

I have function inside my bash script for backup my elasticsearch

```
backup () {
if curator_cli --timeout 600 --host 192.168.2.11 --port 9200 snapshot --repository $SNAPSHOT_NAME --name snapshot-$DATE --filter_list "{\"filtertype\":\"pattern\",\"kind\":\"regex\",\"value\":\".*\"}"
then
 echo backup done
else
 echo backup failed
}
```

but when i launch this script, it prints error

```
./elasticsearch_backup.sh
./elasticsearch_backup.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./elasticsearch_backup.sh: line 21: `}'
```

so how to use curly braces inside bash function?

Comment: You should quote the strings you're trying to `echo`. So: `echo "backup done"` and `echo "backup failed"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` statement in bash must be finished with `fi`:

```sh
backup () {
if curator_cli --timeout 600 --host 192.168.2.11 --port 9200 snapshot --repository $SNAPSHOT_NAME --name snapshot-$DATE --filter_list "{\"filtertype\":\"pattern\",\"kind\":\"regex\",\"value\":\".*\"}"
then
 echo backup done
else
 echo backup failed
fi
}
```